# Error to upload my db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I have a little problem with my code, and I never see that kind of error, I make a second page to edit my post (eg like a profile page with devise). So, when I want to edit a post, it's always the first post of my db which take the changes informations.

So if you can see which terrible mistake I do, it will be amazing!!

Routes :

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pushs/show'

  get 'pushs/edit'

  get 'profiles/show'

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

  resources :posts do 
    resources :comments
end

  get ':pseudo', to: 'profiles#show', as: :profile
  get ':pseudo/edit', to: 'profiles#edit', as: :edit_profile
  patch ':pseudo/edit', to: 'profiles#update', as: :update_profile

  get 'push/:post_id', to: 'pushs#show', as: :push
  get 'push/:post_id/edit', to: 'pushs#edit', as: :edit_push
  patch 'push/:post_id/edit', to: 'pushs#update', as: :update_push

  root 'posts#index'
```

Push controller:

```html
class PushsController < ApplicationController
  
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_push

  def show
    @post = Post.find_by(params[:post_id])
  end

  def edit
  end


 def update
  
    if @post.update(push_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Your profile has been updated.'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @post.errors.full_messages
      flash[:error] = @post.errors.full_messages
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def push_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:prix, :portion)
  end


  def owned_push 
    @post = Post.find_by(params[:id])
    unless current_user == @post.user_id
      flash[:alert] = "That prost doesn't belong to you!"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end


  def set_push
    @post = Post.find_by(params[:id])
  end



end
```

Edit views (push)

```html
<h1>Mettre le Plat en ligne :</h1>


<div class="posts-wrapper">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-body">
      <div class="image-wrap">
        <%= form_for @post, url: {action: "update"}, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group text-center">
                <h4>prix</h4>
                <%= f.text_area :prix %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group text-center">
                <h4>portion</h4>
                <%= f.text_area :portion %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <%= f.submit "Update Post", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to see more, you can check my code on github:
https://github.com/Mesnet/Beta0.1

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: there is no error message, is just that when i try to modify this part of the post, this change is added to my first db post. While I would like this change to be applied to the post edited

Comment: can you post the params hash?

Answer (score 0):

you're looking up `@post` with the param `post_id`, but on the edit page the param you're typically going to use if you have a conventional rails app is just id.

Try adding:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

on the first line of your update action. Let me know if that doesn't solve. And please update your question to include the params hash that is coming through in the stack trace when you post your form.

Comment: Well i don't really understand what you mean by params, so I push all my project on github :https://github.com/Mesnet/Beta0.1